# Why this conditional variation and expectation equality holds?

Tags: probability

Assume $(X_i)_{i\ge 0}$ are random variables (not necessarily martingale) adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\ge 0}$. I found a statement that says

$$\text{Var}(X_{i+1}-X_i\mid\mathcal{F}_i)=E((X_{i+1}-X_i)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_i).$$

I am wondering why this is true?

Comment: I think you require some more conditions, this statement doesn't look true in general. Are $X_i$ adapted to $\mathcal F_i$? Maybe it is a martingale?

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_i$, but is not martingale. (I revised the problem to make this point more clear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have :
$$
Var(X_{i+1} - X_i | \mathcal F_i) = E[(X_{i+1} - X_i - E(X_{i+1} - X_i | \mathcal F_i) )^2|\mathcal F_i] \\ = E[(X_{i+1} - X_i)^2 | \mathcal F_i] \color{red}{-E[X_{i+1} - X_i | \mathcal F_i]^2}
$$

which follows from expanding the square, linearity and usual conditional variance rules. The term in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ can be zero if $X_{i}$ were a martingale (or $X_{i+1}-X_i$ forms a series of "martingale differences", which are used in the proof of variance inequalities like Efron-Stein), but if it is not zero then the statement you give does not hold.